# Function to add a column based on the input from a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from datetime import date, timedelta
yf.pdr_override()

end = date.today()
start = end - timedelta(days=7300)

# download dataframe
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo('^GSPC', start=start, end= end)
```

Now, that I have the dataframe, I want to create a function to add the logarithmic return based on a column to the dataframe called 'data', with the following code:

```
data['log_return'] = np.log(data['Adj Close'] / data['Adj Close'].shift(1))
```

How I think the function should look like is like this:

```
def add_log_return(df):
    
    # add returns in a logarithmic fashion
    added = df.copy()
    added["log_return"] = np.log(df[column] / df[column].shift(1))
    added["log_return"] = added["log_return"].apply(lambda x: x*100)
    return added
```

How can I select a specific column as an input of the function add_log_return(df['Adj Close']), so the function adds the logarithmic return to my 'data' dataframe?

```
data = add_log_return(df['Adj Close'])
```

Comment: Why not pass _two_ arguments: the dataframe and the column name?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you want to copy the entire dataframe, add a column, and return that. If I were you, I'd just take the single column as input and return the calculated series instead, and let the caller do whatever they want with it.

Comment: Also also, why do you need to apply a lambda? You can just do `added["log_return"] = added["log_return"] * 100`, or better yet multiply by 100 when you originally calculate it: `added["log_return"] = np.log(df[column] / df[column].shift(1)) * 100`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thank you for your comments. You are right, I did not think about adding another argument... With regards to your other comments, I have tried the following and it is not working, could you please add some insight?  
`def add_log_return(df, column):
    added = np.log(df[column] / df[column].shift(1))*100
    return added`
df = pd.DataFrame
df['log_return'] = add_log_return(data, 'Adj Close')

Comment: As you can see, code is nearly unreadable in comments. Please [edit] ay changes to your code into your question, and specify what you mean by _"not working"_

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I was doing it incorrectly, thank you very much for taking the time to answer. Could you please post your answer, so I can mark this question as answered? Basically, I have solved it by adding another argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an argument `column` to your function!

```
def add_log_return(df, column): 
    # add returns in a logarithmic fashion
    added = df.copy()
    added["log_return"] = np.log(df[column] / df[column].shift(1)) * 100
    return added

new_df = add_log_return(old_df, 'Adj_Close')
```

<sup>Note I removed the line in your function to apply a lambda that just multiplied by 100. It's much faster to do this in a vectorized manner, by including it in the `np.log(...)` line</sup>

However, if I were you, I'd just return the `Series` object instead of copying the dataframe and modifying and returning the copy.

```
def log_return(col: pd.Series) -> np.ndarray: 
    return np.log(col / col.shift(1)) * 100
```

Now, the caller can do what they want with it:

```
df['log_ret'] = log_return(df['Adj_Close'])
```